# Regex for multiple Instances of Tags in XML

Tags: regex, xml

I got an xml which i want to parse, heres is an example of it:

```
<server name="thisServer" dns="...".....>
...
<path>firstPath</path>
<path>secondPath</path>
<path>thirdPath</path>
...
</server>
```

Now the result should be somehow like:

- which server
- got which paths

Example for the pseudocode above:

GrpNo. | Value

1 | thisServer

2 | firstPath

3 | secondPath

4 | thirdPath

this pattern just gives me the last occurence:

```
<server name="(.*?)".\b[^>]*>.*<path>(.*?)</path>.*</server>
```

I get all paths using

```
<server name="(.*?)".\b[^>]*>.*<path>(.*?)</path>.*<path>(.*?)</path>.*<path>(.*?)</path>.*</server>
```

but that's not the way it should work because I dont know how many paths there may be...

I'm pretty new to this RegEx Stuff and I couldn't find any similar question using the search.

I hope anybody can help me out here :)

Comment: Don't use RegEx for XML use a parser and if possible XPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<server[^"]+"([^"]+)|<path>([^<]+)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/oE6jJ1/49

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'<server[^"]+"([^"]+)|<path>([^<]+)', re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
test_str = u"<server name=\"thisServer\" dns=\"...\".....>\n...\n<path>firstPath</path>\n<path>secondPath</path>\n<path>thirdPath</path>\n...\n</server>"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```